# To fork or not to fork in 2021?

Tags: linux, systemd

Now days services are managed by `systemd` or can be easily wrapped with Debian's old `start-stop-daemon` utility for `init.d`.

Is there any cases when forking is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer hasn't really changed since 2010.

It depends on what the alternative is:

If you're converting pre-systemd daemons to run in systemd .services and have to choose between "simple" and "forking", then Type=forking can have a distinct advantage over Type=simple (assuming the daemon supports both): it allows the service manager to know when the service has *finished initializing.* That is, systemd can distinguish "active" services from "activating" ones.

This can make a lot of difference if you have other services depending on this one. With just Type=simple, they might start too early, before this service has had any time to read configuration, set up sockets, open databases, etc., and this might cause the dependants to fail.

(Note that systemd marks the service as "active" not when the process forks, but when its initial (parent) process *exits,* i.e. very similarly to how commands run from a shell would behave. So the above can apply to other init systems, too: for example, with traditional init.d scripts, `myservice --daemon` would still let the script know that the daemon is taking its time to start up, but `myservice &` will put it in background immediately and the script will not have that information.

But not all daemons actually implement this correctly to begin with – they sometimes "daemonize" as early as they could, before loading the actual configuration and the rest. In this case, Type=forking is unfortunately just as useless as Type=simple.)

But if you're comparing Type=forking with the newer Type=notify (which requires the daemon have special support – it has to send an explicit notification over a socket), then in general the forking mode has no advantages as Type=notify can do the same and more.

Comment: I about new services